# Two ways of comparing UIImages show different results. Which one to believe?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I'm trying to compare two UIImages. If i compare it like this:

```
if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation ( holderImage) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_image.png"])])
            NSLog(@"empty image");
        else
            NSLog(@"not empty image");
```

the result is YES, THEY'RE EQUAL

if i'm doing the following

```
` if ([holderImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty_image.png"]])
            NSLog(@"empty image");
        else
            NSLog(@"not empty image"); `
```

the result is NO, THEY'RE NOT

The situation is pretty complicated because:

1) Images MUST BE (it means i'm pretty much sure)equal so i would believe the first one unless

2) isEqual comparison always gives true result on other images.

So i'm completely confused. What do you think about that? Btw the holderImage was just taken from NSUserDefaults. Do you think it might be changed somehow while being stored in NSUserDefaults so that isEqual comparison is lying now?

Answer (score 7):

The `isEqual` method on `UIImage` looks a the pointer/hash of the object where as the `isEqual` method on `NSData` will look it the bytes are the same.

The `isEqual` used by most object are based on [hash](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a). In the Apple documentation it is specified that `NSData` implements the [`isEqual`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSData) method in a different way.

> Two data objects are equal if they hold the same number of bytes, and if the bytes at the same position in the objects are the same.

Comment: Are you sure? Usually if i compare [myImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]] (and i KNOW they're the same) comparison says they're equal. Does [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] have a pointer to be compared?

Comment: No not real sure, but because when both images are loaded via the `imageNamed` methode the same object is returned since the `imageNamed` uses caching.

Comment: @rckoenes I believe the cache may undergo some optimization. We were using `isEqual` and `imageNamed` in unit tests, and it works great in some situations, but in others it returns NO when the NSData comparison passes.

Answer (score 4):

[PivotalCoreKit](https://github.com/pivotal/PivotalCoreKit) provides a [helper](https://github.com/pivotal/PivotalCoreKit/blob/master/UIKit/SpecHelper/Extensions/UIImage+Spec.m) for comparing the images via bytes. This will pass if the images are created via different sources (eg. `[UIImage -UIImageNamed]` and `[UIImage initWithData:]`, unlike `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`.

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToByBytes:(UIImage *)otherImage {
    NSData *imagePixelsData = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage));
    NSData *otherImagePixelsData = (NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(otherImage.CGImage));

    BOOL comparison = [imagePixelsData isEqualToData:otherImagePixelsData];

    CGDataProviderRelease((CGDataProviderRef)imagePixelsData);
    CGDataProviderRelease((CGDataProviderRef)otherImagePixelsData);
    return comparison;
}
```

Comment: You can also use 'CFBridgingRelease': NSData *imagePixelsData = (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage))); ... That way you don't need to release manually (CGDataProviderRelease), but ARC takes care of that.